# video recording from web browser

Tags: java, http, jsp

i have asked to create a module that will record video messages form the web browser it self.

what technologies, i should look at. and how should i start. please give me some pointers.

A sample code will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at Flash. Flash can access video devices and capture from them. YouTube is a great example of how it works.

Comment: Thanks. I used Flash to get this project done. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Flash (or red5) is today the only way to capture video/sound from a browser.
This [example](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/) is based on red5